# Discrete log problem modified

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory

Suppose one is given an odd prime $p$, a generator $g$ of $(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)^*$ and two integers $a$ and $b$. Is there an efficient method to determine whether $\log_g a < \log_g b$? (Here we are defining $\log_g x$ as between one and $p-1$ inclusive.)

Bonus question added later: What if we restrict the problem to $b=-a$?

Comment: For your bonus question, note that
$$\log_g(a)\equiv\log_g(-a)+\frac{p-1}{2}\pmod{p-1}.$$
So you're asking if we can determine whether $\log_g(a)$ is in the interval $[1,\frac{p-1}{2}]$ or in the interval $[\frac{p+1}{2},p-1]$. It seems as if answering that question for $g^ka$ for various $k$ could be used to compute $\log_g(a)$, but since I haven't worked out the details, I'm just posting this as a comment.

Comment: @JoeSilverman yes that is correct. If solving discrete log is hard, can we at least easily determine which interval $\log_g a$ is in?

Comment: Look up the Blum-Micali algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there were a way of doing this in time polynomial in $\log(p)$, you could solve discrete logarithm in time polynomial in $\log(p)$ by doing a binary search.  That is, to find $\log_g(a)$, first see if $\log_g a < \log_g (g^{(p-1)/2})$.  If yes, next compare  $\log_g(a)$ to $\log_g (g^{\lfloor (p-1)/4\rfloor})$, if no to $\log_g(g^{\lfloor 3 (p-1)/4 \rfloor})$, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I just added a bonus question.